# Move an element with arrow keys

Tags: javascript

```
function docReady()
{
    image = document.getElementById("someImage");
    window.addEventListener("keydown", moveImage);
}

function moveImage(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 37)
        image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) - 5 + 'px';

    if (e.keyCode == 38)
        image.style.top = parseInt(image.style.top) - 5 + 'px';

    if (e.keyCode == 39)
        image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

    if (e.keyCode == 40)
        image.style.top = parseInt(image.style.top) + 5 + 'px';

    console.log(image.style.left + ', ' + image.style.top);
}
```

So the code above is supposed to move an image around. However, it doesn't. The console returns blanks for `image.style.left` and `image.style.top`. Could you help me with fixing it?

**P.S.** If you would be so kind, can you also make it so that if the image is on the screen borders it will stop moving? Thank you so much!

Comment: "I have tried a few different methods, and they all worked using more or less the same code, only this version doesn't seem to work". Why not just use one of the methods that works?

Comment: I'm the kid in the class that always raises his hand to give an alternate answer xp but anyways thanks all! I'm so dumb, all I needed was to set an inital value for top and left in docReady....

Comment: Lol, well just be mindful to stop coming up with alternatives at some point. There is a countably infinite number of ways to do anything.

Comment: Regarding your P.S. - just check each time an arrow button is clicked that the corresponding value is not out of the window frame (i.e., has the coordinates less than height/width of the viewport and greater than zero)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some steps indeed.

To be precise, you should:

- create the variable `image` outside the function (i.e., declare it global)
- set the initial values of `top`, `left`
- set the position of your element to `absolute`. Default is `static` and it doesn't support moving/styling with top/left/right/bottom.
- call the whole thing on page load

And here's what you get once you follow the above steps:

```js
window.onload = docReady;
var image;

function docReady() {
    image = document.getElementById("someImage");
    window.addEventListener("keydown", moveImage);
    image.style.left = 0;
    image.style.top = 0;
}

function moveImage(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37)
        image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) - 5 + 'px';

    if (e.keyCode == 38)
        image.style.top  = parseInt(image.style.top)  - 5 + 'px';

    if (e.keyCode == 39)
        image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

    if (e.keyCode == 40)
        image.style.top  = parseInt(image.style.top)  + 5 + 'px';

    console.log(image.style.left + ', ' + image.style.top);
}
```

```css
#someImage{ 
   position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id = "someImage"> not an image but a test </div>
```

(For the simplicity I'm using a plain text element instead of image, but that doesn't matter)